# TSQL : 'exec sp_databasex' return nothing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an application that uses `exec sp_databases` to check if a database exist.

But on a new instance of SQL Server, this query return nothing. With SQL Server Management Studio, I can see the database.

Can you explain what this query done?

What right is necessary?

And that check?

Comment: you mean `exec sp_databases` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176070.aspx):

> Requires `CREATE DATABASE`, or `ALTER ANY DATABASE`, or `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` permission, and must have access permission to the database. Cannot be denied `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` permission.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be

```
exec sp_databases -- note the last s
```